# Auto create POJO class from database in IntelliJ

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide

Is there any function in IntelliJ that allows me to generate simple POJO class from database tables (currently using PSQL)? I saw some similar example in Eclipse using "hbm2java".

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, it's possible to generate simple POJOs from Database Tables in IntelliJ.

Just follow this instruction:

1. Connect your database to IntelliJ.
2. Right click the tables you want to generate your POJOs for
3. Right Click on your selection --> Scripted Extensions --> Generate POJOs.groovy
4. Select where to save your POJO classes
5. Press OK and your POJO files will be created.

Hope this helps. 
- Tested on IntelliJ 2019.1

Comment: I did the same and instead of POJO it only created "Generate POJOs.groovy" in the selected folder.

Comment: Got it. It works only if you right-click on the tables not on the db.

Comment: Unable to see Generate POJOs.groovy option.. Is this option available in Intellij community edition. I'm using 2020.1?

Comment: I don't know about that unfortunately as I am using full edition due to developing Enterprise Applications

Comment: is this available in community edition of intellij?

Answer (score 0):

It is still possible, but in newer versions you need to have "POJO Generator" plugin installed, then:

1. Open database View | Tool Windows | Database
2. In the Database tool window ( View | Tool Windows | Database) , click the Data Source Properties button
3. In the Database tool window ( View | Tool Windows | Database) , click the Add button, choose you db type
4. Here you fill host, username/pass and etc.
5. Right click the tables you want to generate your POJOs for and you will see 'POJO generator' at the bottom of the list
6. Choose Entity and place in project where to save it